# frequent crashes and freezes on Linux

Tags: performance, linux

#### My problem

I recently removed gdm3 from my system to switch to KDE Plasma. Since then, the normal blender starter shortcut doesn't work any more; the program appears in the taskbar and, without showing a window, it disappears, leaving no crash report behind.

I can run it in the terminal, but for unknown reasons, it has huge performance issues in the editor. If I try to open a remotely complex scene, it takes between 30 seconds and multiple minutes to open the scene.
In the editor, it runs smoothly as long as I don't do anything. Especially in edit mode of a model (in this case with about 2.500 triangles) it takes a minute to subdivide a single rectangle or add a cube to the mesh.

While those operations were pending, blender is frozen, sometimes it even froze the whole system except for the cursor.

#### What I've tried

I tried to run blender with debug information (`blender --debug --debug-all`), but I didn't get any errors or warnings.

I tried to reinstall blender from multiple sources (dnf, flatpak, snap, steam), but it changed nothing. I even installed the Windows version on Steam and ran it through proton, which resulted in the same problem.

Furthermore, I researched a lot, but I didn't come to a solution which changed anything for me.

#### Observations

I noticed that blender seems to have a limit at 12.5% of CPU usage.
I ran btop and observed the process. It didn't have any memory problems as far as I understood, but it took 12.5% CPU while an operation was running. Btop showed, in the upper left corner of the process details, that it used 100% CPU, which let me think it has some kind of restriction to 12.5%.
Furthermore, I noticed that it always uses one CPU core on 100%, while the others are below 10%; the used core switched during the process, but it was always one doing all the work.

Here is a screenshot of the product details in btop while I'm subdividing a rectangle:
[image: the btop details of the process]

#### Specs

- Blender version: 4.0.2
- Windowing system detected by blender: WAYLAND
- OS: Fedora 39 ThirtyNine
- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 6.7.9-200.fc39.x86_64
- Shell: fish 3.7.0
- DE: KDE 5.115.0 / Plasma 5.27.11
- WM: KWin
- CPU: Intel Core i5-9300H @ 8x 4.1GHz
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design
- RAM: 15830MiB

It's important to notice, that I didn't have this issue before on the same machine and in the same scenes, so it's likely not hardware related.
Does anyone here have an idea how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a bug, you could report it using the help menu inside Blender

Comment: Hi, TheLinus. This really is a problem for the developers, we're not qualified to test and give definitive advice for problems we can't all reproduce in our own installations. We are here to help as much as we can with the **use** of the application and its API. So, sorry, this is off topic-on Blender SE. Please make a bug report. (I'm a KDE Plasma user, but X11.. maybe it's a Wayland thing?)